# Wifi killer 1650 with AX 200 Chipset super slow on WINDOWS 5GHZ Wifi 6

Tags: wireless-networking, iperf3

I'm having a very slow connection with only 60Mbit-90Mbit in 5Ghz WiFi 6

1. WiFi Card `killer 1650 (ax 200)` chipset
2. `TP-link AX23` (put next to my pc)
3. `Windows` OS

I have tried to test speed with `iperf3` with other devices with conclusion other devices iperf to each other could hit `600mbit` easily but not to my PC with `killer 1650`

1. Macbook air
2. lenovo thinkpad
3. Matepad huawei 10.4

things i have done

1. Install dual boot `Ubuntu 22` and works charm, get speed as expected but when back to windows 10 is slow
2. update BIOS for `asrock b450 pro4`: nothing changed
3. **reinstall** `windows 10` to `windows 11`, nothing changed
4. install older driver: nothing changed

so i am getting frustrated because TP LINK AX23 mention could hit 1200 Mbits/s with wifi6

here are pictures
[image]
[image]

any ideas on this?

Comment: (1) Have you installed the [latest drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/211610/intel-killer-wifi-6-ax1650-is/downloads.html)? (2) The opposite advice is to uninstall all the killer software & driver and reboot to use the Microsoft driver. (3) Have you tried another WiFi card, or even an external USB network adapter?

Comment: 1) yes i tried with latest driver first only trying to look workaround 2) i dont have killer software installed on fresh install windows 11 and first try on windows 10, 3) yes, i did actually. i tried the ax200 (non killer) and its the same so i returned it to the shop, exchanged with killer 1.

Comment: More: (1) *Power Options < Change Plan Options < Change Advanced Power Settings > Wireless Adapter Settings > Power Saving Mode* change “Setting” to “Maximum Performance” on both “On battery” and “Plugged in”. (2) Properties of the network adapter, Advanced, change Wireless Mode to "08 - 11 a/b/g/n". (3) Disable Bluetooth, (4)  Change your network adapter to non-Killer.

Comment: thanks for the reply @harrymc. 1) i checked its already on maximum on every profiles, i think its maxixmum by default on PC since not battery powered 2) u mean on the device manager? there already a//b/g/n/ax 3) tried any the same 4) tried with ordinary ax200 also having same issue

Comment: You're only testing Killer hardware/software, so may encounter repeatedly the same problem. Try non-Killer hardware, even just an external USB adapter.

Comment: the funny thing is i did, yes, i did actually. i tried the ax200 (non killer) and its having the same issue so i returned it to the shop, exchanged with killer 1, for the usb is non 5GHZ, is my older device before i upgrade to this pcie wifi card

Comment: (1) A [post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Very-slow-download-speeds-with-intel-wifi-6-ax200/td-p/1236541/page/2) suggests using an older driver, mentioning version `21.80.2` (which one is yours?). (2) A later answer in this post recommends doing `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a few things. First try to disable autotuning via the command line;

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

Second (this happened to me on a bad cable on ethernet on a MacBook, but might also happen on WiFi and Windows) is that the interace unfairly gets downgraded to `100baseTX`. You want to look this up in your adapter settings via de device manager and see if you can manually force it to `1000baseT` (1Gbit) and `Full Duplex`, because your test clearly shows a `100Mbit` upper limit. In my case it was even stranger, because mine was bouncing randomly between 100~250Mbit.

Sorry for not showing more details with paths and images, since I currently don't have a Windows device present to share the exact steps.

I hope it helps or sets you on the right path!

**Edit;** I found this image online for which I was referring to, but it shows 100Mbps in the image. Here choose 1.0Gbit or 1000Mbps (Full Duplex) (depending on the interface settings). It's not relevant that this is ethernet. It should be the same for WiFi interfaces;

[image]

Comment: thankyou for the repsonse. but, unfortunately, the `settings` you show and  the `case example of macbook` is for `ethernet connection`, not `Wi-Fi connection` :)

Comment: That's true. But it there might've been something you could work with with your adapter. My TP-Link Archer USB WiFi stick also had all kinds of these settings. But it's very obvious from your tests that your adapter is hard-locked at 100mbps. Windows is likely choking it somewhere with the drivers and/or adapter settings. Otherwise its maybe possible to test the same adapter on another computer to see if it behaves the same.

Comment: yes unfortunately that option only available in the `ethernet`, uinfortunately i dont have other PC, thats why im using other device for tab and macbook. BUT i tried on same PC with ubuntu 22 OS everything is good

Answer (score 0):

@david Just replace Wireless Wifi Antenna and it's Ipex cable Connector of your system And check. Few months back i also faced this issue. After changing Antenna and connector i got exact speed.

Comment: "Google it" is not an answer IMO.

Comment: thanks for the response but i did put the router next to my PC, so wiFi signal by antenae types shouldnt be issue

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Very slow download speeds with intel wifi 6 ax200](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Very-slow-download-speeds-with-intel-wifi-6-ax200/td-p/1236541/page/2)
treats the question.

One
[answer](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Very-slow-download-speeds-with-intel-wifi-6-ax200/m-p/1388065/highlight/true#M42032)
suggests using an older driver, mentioning specifically version 21.80.2
as the last version which worked correctly. All later version (according
to the answer) have this problem.

Another
[answer](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Very-slow-download-speeds-with-intel-wifi-6-ax200/m-p/1393531/highlight/true#M42262)
in this post recommends doing :

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal.
```

Comment: i haven't try the solution yet, but this answer relates to the question, so i give bounty to this first, ill update the result later